# variable unexpectedly changing

Tags: c

I'm learning the C and writing a program to calculate factorials. When I print the value of the variable it is displayed as "1111111111". I checked and upon initialization it is "1". I think its possibly an overflow but the problem is I do not know why it is happening. For the first iteration the prev_num variable should read "1".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int prev_num = 1;
    int n = 0;

    for (n=1; n<=10; n++)
        printf("%i", prev_num);
        prev_num = prev_num * n;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a '\n' for the `printf ()` :) This is also why you should always use {} around your blocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotton the brackets around your for loop:

```
 for (n=1; n<=10; n++) {
        printf("%i\n", prev_num);
        prev_num = prev_num * n;
 }
```

Also, add a newline character to list the numbers below each other.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the computer sees your program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int prev_num = 1;
    int n = 0;

    for (n=1; n<=10; n++)        // The loop runs 10 times
    {
        printf("%i", prev_num);  // Every time, print the value "1"
    }

    prev_num = prev_num * n;     // This line is NOT part of the loop!

    return 0;
}
```

Indenting a line does not make it part of a loop.
Only putting `{` `}` around a set of statements makes it part of a loop.

When there are no brackets, only ONE line below the loop will be part of the loop.